# Regular Expression to check doubles, triples etc

Tags: c#, regex

I need regular expression to retrieve no of doubles, triplets, tetras etc from a telephone number

following is the example, 
number is 1001055522
it should return me

```
group              Numbers
=============================
Doubles            00
                   22 
Triplets           555
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Just use a loop and count!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Do you mean you have an obvious regex answer ? I don't.

Comment: Why use a regex if there is a simpler way ?

Comment: please post some of that code so that we can help you

Comment: OP, when you have the choice between finding a magical regex and a few simple lines of boring code, you might choose the second solution if the first one doesn't seem easy enough.

Comment: Here's a tip. If your question doesn't actually contain a question, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @dystroy: Neither do I. But I would at least expect an explanation by the OP why he/she thinks regex is the best choice in this situation, and what others solutions he/she has considered and discarded before coming to the conclusion that it must be regex even though he/she cannot solve the issue using regex him-/herself.

Comment: I think in this case a loop answer is more efficient, both in terms of code clarity, and speed.

Comment: WEll guys thanks for your considerations, in fact i have to separate Golden numbers from a 7 digit number starting from 1 to 9999999. and dump them in db in different tables so that whenever an Admin user wants to assign the available numbers to any request he may easily assign the number simple by selection. Now about the Question Regex. i think regex is the fastest string matching lib. Well i think i should go for the loop one. the Thumb logic :)

Comment: But in this case you don't need anything more complicated than a single scan of the string in a loop. A regex can't possibly be more efficient than that.

Answer (score 3):

This regex when used with `Regex.Matches` will produce exact double or triple (not part of longer consecutive sequence). This is due to the greediness of the quantifier.

```
(\d)\1+
```

[**Demo**](http://www.regex101.com/r/cN1rU8)

Well, the rest is to check the length of the string and count... I will leave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

To find doubles, use a backreference:

```
(.)\1
```

Here's a demo: http://regex101.com/r/zC3fM1

---

To find triplets, just repeat the backreference:

```
(.)\1{2}
```

Here's a demo: http://regex101.com/r/cJ4lJ8

---

If you want to match all consecutive numbers regardless of how many there are, then use `+` on the backreference:

```
(.)\1+
```

Here's a demo: http://regex101.com/r/pL8sB3

Comment: How about double that is part of triple?

Comment: @nhahtdh - Yes. The `.` matches 1, and the `\1{2}` matches 2 more.

Comment: No, I mean your regex will match 55 in 555

Comment: @nhahtdh - The OP never said that that's a problem.

Comment: He clearly shows it in the question that he wants 00 and 22 as double, and 555 as triple.

Comment: Matching the 55 in 555 is obviously a problem.  Regex is a dirty solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim n = "1001055522"

Dim doubles = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(n, "(.)\1")
Dim triples = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(n, "(.)\1{2}")

'Doubles
For Each d As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In doubles
    Console.WriteLine(d.Value)
Next

'Triples
For Each t As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In triples
    Console.WriteLine(t.Value)
Next
```

Comment: no its not the solution, in this case the result should be 2 doubles and 1 tripple